# Change filename with multer NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I have to upload a file which the name depends of a varible sended to the request. So I have a variable declared, `imageType`, to use in the `multer.diskStorage`an I have another variable for de dynamic path too, `imagePath` which it's working in the same way that I'm using the `imageType`, but I'm getting `undefined-logo.jpg` from the `imageType`. Here is the code:

```
var imagePath = '';
var imageType = '';
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, imagePath);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, (imageType + '-logo.jpg'));
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

router.route('/representatives/:id/loginLogo')
    .post((req, res, next) => {
    /////SOME CODE BEFORE/////
    if (rows[0].client_directory == '') {
        imagePath = `${rows[0].subdomain_directory}`;
    } else {
        imagePath = `${rows[0].subdomain_directory}/${rows[0].client_directory}/`;
    }
    imageType = req.body.imageType;

upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
       return next(err);
    }
    var sql = `UPDATE representatives SET login_logo = 'jpg' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
    conn.query(sql, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json({ message: 'Image uploaded!', representative: req.body.imageType}); //HERE RETURNS req.body.imageType OK
    })
  })
})
```

Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: what does console.log(req.body.imageType) say?

Comment: So, you have your answer. req.body itself doesn't contain imageType.

Comment: It returns undefined, but after that I use the upload function and when it's finished it returns `res.json({ message: 'Image uploaded!', representative: req.body.imageType});` and the name it's fine

Comment: Care adding complete code?

Comment: Also, you could grab fileType from file.originalName. Just grab the last part

Comment: I've updated the code above